# Microsoft Excel value lookup, return result in an undefined number of row above

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know how to use the vlookup function to search my worksheet to return the value. However, what if the value that I want is in an undefined number of row above.

Example below, if I were to search for # of house > 0, then return the name of the city. How do I do that? Please note that I can't change the input file, because it's feed in from other places. Thanks alot!

```
City 1  
num of cars 5

num of houses   3

City 2  
num of planes   5

num of cars 50

num of houses   3

City 3  
num of planes   10

num of houses   300

num of men  3
```

---

To answer the questions:

1. If more than one record is found, then return all result (names of the cities)
2. And yes, the hard part is that the number of rows is not always the same. The logic to be used to determine how many rows above the found cell is only to do a search for word 'city', this keyword is always there
3. If the non-city rows start with others then this can't be done? The cell before the 'num of' is actual numbers #0001, #0002...

Comment: What happens when more than one record matches your criteria, should it return first, last, all, error?

Comment: In addition to the above request for clarification: it seems as if "num of houses" is not always the same number of rows below its respective city. What logic can be applied to determine how many rows above the found cell the city is ?

Comment: I only see this happening through VBA scripting and that too if you guarantee that non-city rows start with "num of".

Answer (score 1):

A little messy (because of not bothering to remove blank rows) and requires a 'helper column' (here ColumnA with a label added) but a PivotTable would bypass any difficulty with variable numbers or rows:

[image: SU586468 example]

Comment: pnuts, thanks, this seems to work only under the condition of column A has to be created, anyway to create Column A without manually doing the work? I have a long list of few thousand items... Thanks!